Fill a face with only 2 sides known
I am farily new to blender.
Is there a way to fill in a face with only 2 edges as shown in the diagram.

I understand that blender cannot guess what shape I want from only 2 sides however in this case I wanted a rectangle shape fill.
To make the face, I extruded one of the end points and then located the new end point a coordinate that would form an exact rectangle at the end of the object. Then filled the edge, then selected 3 edges and used fill (F). I was able to calculate and change the coordinates of the new point because the object was parallel to the vertices (x/y/z) and therefore create an accurate rectangle fill. However if the object was rotated I would not have been able to calculate the new coordinates without a lot of math.
Is there a better/simpler way of doing this (creating a rectangle fill like this) no matter what angle the object is positioned in ?
Hope this is clear.

Try using Blender's built-in F2 addon. That should do exactly what you want. There's a very old (11 year-old!) but still relevant tutorial from Kent Trammell at CG Cookie here which should do exactly what you want.

Thank you John, that worked perfectly.

@JohnEason It is a good question and answer. Could you kindly post an answer? I will upvote it :)

@HarryMcKenzie Will do. - Have been out.

You can use Blender's built-in F2 addon to do exactly that. If it isn't already enabled, go to Edit > Preferences > Addons and type f2 into the search field. Check the Mesh:F2 entry to enable it.

In Edit > Vertex mode, click the corner vertex of the area you want to fill and hit F > ⏎ Enter. (if you don't hit ⏎ Enter to complete the operation the created vertex of the face will remain active and can be moved around with the mouse as if you'd hit G which probably isn't what you want.


thanks for posting it! :)
